# Event to NumericUpDown for only user interaction

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, events, numericupdown

I have 3 `NumericUpDown` elements in my form. This elements is synchronized by their sum. For example sum is 9 elements values is 3,3,3 and increment is 2. When user is changed first element up from 3 to 5 we must get 5,2,2.

For synchronized I had tried to use events `ValueChanged` and `VisibleChanged`, but they working when we have a programmatic modification or user interaction.
I used this method for every element, but for this events this method starts changing again, when result values other elements is changing in a code.

```
 private void numericUpDown1Change(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int oldValue = Sum - (int)numericUpDown2.Value - (int)numericUpDown3.Value;
        int average;
        if ((int)numericUpDown1.Value - oldValue > 0)
        {
            average = ((int)numericUpDown1.Value - oldValue) / 2;
            numericUpDown2.Value = numericUpDown2.Value - average;
            numericUpDown3.Value = numericUpDown3.Value - average;
        }
        else
        {
            average = (oldValue - (int)numericUpDown1.Value) / 2;
            numericUpDown2.Value = numericUpDown2.Value + average;
            numericUpDown3.Value = numericUpDown3.Value + average;
        }
    }
```

I want to use event, what worked just when user clicking the up or down button, or by the user entering a new value.

**What event I must choose for it?**

Comment: Some code and your actual problem would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `ValueChanged` event, but keep a flag telling you if the change is done by code or by user.

For a single control you can keep a Boolean variable at the class level (I would probably call it `IsValueChangedByCode`) and set it to `false`. Inside your methods, right before you change the value, set it to `true` and right after that back to `false`. Inside the event handler check that flag is `true` or `false`, and decide if you want to execute the code or not.

For 3 controls the logic is the same, but instead of using a boolean flag, you need 2 different booleans, or you can use an integer or flags enum.